# how to convert map into repeated tuple in scala

Tags: scala, data-structures

I have a method that accepts repeated tuples

`myfn(attributes: (String, Any)*)`

can I convert a map to a repeated tuple ?

for example 
`val m = Map ("a1"->1,"a2"->8) // convert to tuple
myfn(m1)`

Comment: `Map[String, Any]` is a code reek in Scala…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, why not?

```
 def function(myMap.toList(): _*)
```